TinyRadius Message-Authenticator Attribute Generation
Need some help. Have Java Springboot API and ma using TinyRadius to authenticate against Radius Server. Below works fine without passing Message-Authenticator

AccessRequest ar = new AccessRequest(userid, passcode);
ar.setAuthProtocol(AccessRequest.AUTH_PAP);
RadiusPacket response = rc.authenticate(ar);
....
....


I need to send Message-Authenticator attribute and need some help on how do I go about doing that. I tried below it's not working always comes back with timeout it's not liking message-authenticator I am passing, don't know if I am even generating the Message-Authenticator correctly
import org.tinyradius.packet.RadiusPacket;
import org.tinyradius.packet.AccessRequest;
import org.tinyradius.util.RadiusClient;
import org.tinyradius.attribute.RadiusAttribute;

....
.........

        byte[] secret = mySecretValue.getBytes();
        RadiusPacket response = null;
        try {
            byte[] authenticator = MessageAuthenticator.generateAuthenticator(ar, secret);
            ar.addAttribute(new 
            RadiusAttribute(RadiusAttributeType.MESSAGE_AUTHENTICATOR.getValue(), authenticator));
            response = rc.authenticate(ar);
        } catch (Exception e) {            
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

Here is generateAuthenticator implementation
public static byte[] generateAuthenticator(RadiusPacket packet, byte[] secret) throws Exception {
        String HMAC_MD5 = "HmacMD5";
        int AUTHENTICATOR_LENGTH = 16;        
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_MD5);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secret, HMAC_MD5));
        mac.update((byte) packet.getPacketType());
        return mac.doFinal();
    }

//also tried below with noluck

public static byte[] generateAuthenticator2(RadiusPacket packet, byte[] secret, int len) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md5=getMd5Digest();
        md5.reset();
        byte[] requestAuthenticator=new byte[16];
        Random r=new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
            requestAuthenticator[i]=(byte)r.nextInt();
        }
        md5.update(secret,0,len);
        md5.update(requestAuthenticator,0,requestAuthenticator.length);
        return md5.digest();
    }


Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.
